# MongoDB source code compilation error

Tags: python, mongodb

While trying to compile MongoDB source code on linux, i am getting following error:

```
Checking for C library wpcap... no        
scons: done reading SConscript files.      
scons: Building targets ...
/usr/bin/python src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py src/mongo/base/error_codes.err build/linux2/64/usesm/mongo/base/error_codes.h build/linux2/64/usesm/mongo/base/error_codes.cpp           
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py", line 257, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)    
  File "src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py", line 37, in main  
    error_codes, error_classes = parse_error_definitions_from_file(argv[1])  
  File "src/mongo/base/generate_error_codes.py", line 52, in    parse_error_definitions_from_file                                                 
    errors_code = compile(errors_file.read(), errors_filename, 'exec')         
  File "src/mongo/base/error_codes.err", line 2
```

Am I missing any python package which is required for compilation ?

Comment: Why not just install it from a repo?

Comment: I am trying to compile the latest code .. I doubt that the issue is related to some missing python package.  Has anyone seen this error ?

Comment: according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/gWptMGky8f0 you were able to solve this by recloning the repo

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to build MongoDB or PyMongo?

Comment: I was trying to compile mongodb. There was some issue while cloning the files. I cloned the files on windows and transferred it to Linux and thats why this error. 

Thanks
Sunil